# YTD for each asset on a table (Data filtering - Dax)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Imagine a table with 3 columns:

| Date | AssetType | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 1.02 |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 1.05 |
| 2022-01-04 | A | 1.09 |
| 2022-01-05 | A | 1.06 |
| 2022-01-03 | B | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | B | 1.05 |
| 2022-01-05 | B | 1.07 |
| 2022-01-06 | B | 1.09 |
| 2022-01-07 | B | 1.08 |

The First date of 2022 for each asset is diferent.

- Asset A - 2022-01-01
- Asset B - 2022-01-03

I want to create a new column or measure that returns the first date of 2022 for both assets.

So far i've tried to use = CALCULATE(STARTOFYEAR(table[date])), FILTER(Table, Table[AssetType] = [Asset type]

Obs. [Asset Type] is a measure tha giver me the type of asset.

But is returning the same date for both assets (2022-01-01)

Does anyone knows how get this done ?

| Date | AssetType | Value | FirstDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 1.02 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 1.05 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-04 | A | 1.09 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-05 | A | 1.06 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-03 | B | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-04 | B | 1.05 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-05 | B | 1.07 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-06 | B | 1.09 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-07 | B | 1.08 | 2022-01-03 |

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This Time create a calculated column and paste this code:

```
FirstDate =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( YourTable[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( YourTable, YourTable[AssetType] )
)
```

The result :

[image: FG]

Comment: I've eddited in a new table in the original question.
That's what i'm trying to get as a result.
Can you take another look?

Comment: OK. I updated the solution. Please check it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, that works for databases that dont exceed 1 year.

When it does exceed, how would you resolve the issue ?

Comment: You're welcome! It can find the min date even if It exceeds 1 year. You had better test it yourself with real data , and let me know. Stay safe.

Comment: The problem with 1year+ databases is that the min date is not actually what im looking for. I want the first day of the year not the min date of the whole database. So if we add dates for 2021, the [First Date] Column will only return me the first day of that year (2021). That's the problem i'm will be facing when handling bigger databases. Do you know something i can do to work around this ? Thanks a lot by the way, you already helped so much.

Comment: It is still not difficult. You will remove filter from the year column of the date table and DAX will consider the whole year-date range. It is an easy task. If you want to filter a specific year, then you will use calculate filters or filter() function to constraint the rows only belonging to the year indicated.

Comment: Thanks man, i followed your instructions and managed to resolve it.

Comment: Wow! You're great! I am pleased to hear it.